# Specific UIWebView Selections (only entire words/sentences)

Tags: javascript, html, uiwebview, selection

I want users to only be able to select an entire sentences within my UIWebView.  I'm using my own UIMenuItem (a bookmark button) in a UIWebView. I am going to save this bookmark (core data) and would like to determine which sentence/verse the highlight is in.  I am laying out the html programmatically (building up from a sqlite database), and have a `<span id="x">` (where x is a variable integer) surrounding every sentence.  I know that the Amazon Kindle app only lets users select entire words.  How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you saw my updated answer?

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried `setMarkedText:selectedRange:`?

[Apple developer lib](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

**Update:**

While you can't use `setMarkedText` inside the `UIWebView` there is no way but using JavaScript. I don't know, if you can manipulate the HTML page that you are showing or not? you can add this script in the page. If you can't manipulate the page you should load an `iframe` inside your `UIWebView` that loads your actual page and after the `iframe` add this script.

Here is the script:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    if(getSelection().anchorNode != null ){
        var sel = getSelection(),
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0),
            nodeValue = sel.anchorNode.nodeValue,
            lastCharIndex = range.endOffset,
            firstCharIndex = range.startOffset,
            lastChar = nodeValue.substr(lastCharIndex, 1),
            firstChar = nodeValue.substr(firstCharIndex, 1);

        while(lastChar != (" " || ".")){
            lastChar = nodeValue.substr(lastCharIndex, 1);
            lastCharIndex++;
        };

        while(firstChar != " "){
            firstChar = nodeValue.substr(firstCharIndex, 1);
            firstCharIndex--;
        };

        range.setEnd(sel.anchorNode, lastCharIndex-1);
        sel.addRange(range);
        range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, firstCharIndex+2);
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
}, false);
```

I tested this on my iPhone and it was working fine.

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9jsrd/embedded/result/) (just select something).
I spent a lot time on it. I hope you enjoy it.

Comment: This only works for classes that implement the `UITextInput` protocol.  
Also, care to explain how to grab entire sentences, etc?

Comment: I'm new in iOS, I just want to make sure there is no iOSy way. I'll work on a JavaScript way tonight. This question is interesting to me. I hope you would be able to inject JS code into UIWebView